# Convert Delphi VCL Windows app or rewrite?

Tags: ios, delphi

I have a Windows VCL app in Delphi XE5 that I'm looking to convert/rewrite for iOS.  The current app uses a local Firebird database.

I'm looking for suggestions on whether to use a tool to convert the VCL app for iOS use, or whether rewriting is the best way to go.

Comment: See [Migrating VCL Applications to FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Migrating_VCL_Applications_to_FireMonkey) and [Converting Applications from VCL to FireMonkey](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42535)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rewrite your application provided you made it using FMX (FireMonkey) instead of VCL. FMX was introduced with Delphi XE2. Old FMX (The one provided with XE5) will probably not work with recent iOS version. So upgrading Delphi to latest version is highly recommended.

If you wrote your application with VCL, then yes you have to rewrite it with FireMonkey (FMX). This could be not to much difficult as FMX components are close to VCL. The most difficult part is if you use 3rd party visual components. You have to get FMX version.